# jQuery - Update css after JSON append

Tags: jquery, json, append

First time post; long time reader. I've come across this problem and I now know the cause with no end result/fix that I could find. Apologies in advance if this has been answered previously.

I have some data in a php that gets appended via the ajax command within jQuery (JSON). This displays correctly, taking on the particular CSS assigned and such.

I have a time displayed which shows '10 minutes ago' or however long it was posted, but I am trying to get it to display the actual date/time on hover. This is the end product but to get to this point I'm just trying to assign a CSS for visual testing to make sure it does work.

The mouseover command can happen at any point so I can't do it once the JSON data is appended.

```
$("span.post-name").mouseover(function () {
    $(this).css("color","red");
});
```

This function does work on the same span put directly into the HTML, but not on data that is built. Any help would be much appreciated..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the problem with adding a function to content that has been dynamically added? If so, then you would want to use `.on()` and have it look like so:

```
$("body").on("mouseenter", "span.post-name" function(event) {
   ("span.post-name").css("color", "red");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("span.post-name").live('mouseover',function () {
    $(this).css("color","red");
});
```

You need to use **.live** as the new html is inserted on the fly.

Comment: Per: http://api.jquery.com/live/ `.live()` has been deprecated. Using off `.on()` or `.delegate()` is suggested.

Comment: @thnom Please use `.on()` because, "As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated." source: http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: I didn't either until recently. Having to convert all my old `.live()` events has been a pain because `.live()` was so nice and simple!

Comment: Yeah, totally. I guess I'll just have to modify my scripts. What a pain in the ass